# How to apply trait inside a closure which is used as a function result

Tags: rust

I can't implement this LISP construction

```
(defun foo (n)
  (lambda (i) (incf n i)))
```

in Rust.
I have tried [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4ac3983866f53f6ed453&version=stable):

```
use std::ops::Add;

fn f<T: Add>(n: T) -> Box<Fn(T) -> T> {
    Box::new(move |i: T| n + i)
} 

fn main() {
    let adder = f(2);
    assert_eq!(4, adder(2));
}
```

But it causes an error:

```
error: mismatched types:
 expected `T`,
    found `<T as core::ops::Add>::Output`
(expected type parameter,
    found associated type) [E0308]
           Box::new(move |i: T| n + i)
                                ^~~~~
```

Seems like the trait `Add` defined for the outer function was not transferred into the inner closure.

Is it possible to implement such a construction?

It is possible to implement this function with a concrete type instead of a generic:

```
fn f(n: i32) -> Box<Fn(i32) -> i32> {
    Box::new(move |i| n + i)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the pain of generics w.r.t. arithmetic operations in Rust!

Answer (score 7):

There are several problems with the generic version.

First, the error you have provided occurs because just `T: Add` is not enough to specify output type: you need to put a constraint onto the associated type `<T as Add>::Output` as well (see [`Add`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) docs):

```
fn f<T: Add<Output=T>>(n: T) -> Box<Fn(T) -> T> {
    Box::new(move |i: T| n + i)
}
```

Alternatively, you can make the closure return the output type of `<T as Add>`:

```
fn f<T: Add>(n: T) -> Box<Fn(T) -> T::Output> {
    Box::new(move |i: T| n + i)
}
```

However, now you'll get the following error:

```
<anon>:4:10: 4:37 error: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough [E0310]
<anon>:4     Box::new(move |i: T| n + i)
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:4:10: 4:37 help: see the detailed explanation for E0310
<anon>:4:10: 4:37 help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `T: 'static`...
<anon>:4:10: 4:37 note: ...so that the type `[closure@<anon>:4:19: 4:36 n:T]` will meet its required lifetime bounds
<anon>:4     Box::new(move |i: T| n + i)
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The problem here is that `T` may contain references inside it (afterwards, it is a generic type - it can contain *anything*); however, `Box<Fn(T) -> T>` implicitly means that anything inside this trait object must be `'static`, i.e. the compiler automatically adds `'static` constraint: `Box<Fn(T) -> T + 'static>`. However, your closure captures `T` which can contain any references, not only `'static`.

The most general way to fix it would be to add an explicit lifetime constraint of `T` and `Box<Fn(T) -> T>`:

```
fn f<'a, T: Add<Output=T> + 'a>(n: T) -> Box<Fn(T) -> T + 'a> {
    Box::new(move |i: T| n + i)
}
```

Alternatively, you can specify that `T` is `'static`, though this unnecessarily limits the genericity of your code:

```
fn f<T: Add<Output=T> + 'static>(n: T) -> Box<Fn(T) -> T> {
    Box::new(move |i: T| n + i)
}
```

However, this still does not compile:

```
<anon>:4:31: 4:32 error: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
<anon>:4     Box::new(move |i: T| n + i)
                                  ^
```

This error happens because addition in Rust (i.e. `Add` trait) works by value - it consumes both arguments. For `Copy` types, like numbers, it is fine - they are always copied. However, the compiler can't assume that generic type parameters also designate `Copy` types because there is no respective bound, therefore it assumes that values of type `T` can only be moved around. However, you're specifying that the returned closure is [`Fn`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), so it takes its environment by reference. You can't move out of a reference, and this is what this error is about.

There are several ways to fix this error, the simplest one being to add `Copy` bound:

```
fn f<'a, T: Add<Output=T> + Copy + 'a>(n: T) -> Box<Fn(T) -> T + 'a> {
    Box::new(move |i: T| n + i)
}
```

And now it compiles.

One possible alternative would be to return [`FnOnce`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html) closure which takes its environment by value:

```
fn f<'a, T: Add<Output=T> + 'a>(n: T) -> Box<FnOnce(T) -> T + 'a> {
    Box::new(move |i: T| n + i)
}
```

There are two problems with it, however. First, as its name implies, `FnOnce` can only be called once, because upon its first invocation its environment is consumed, and there is nothing to call it on the next time. This may be overly limiting. Second, unfortunately, Rust cannot call `Box<FnOnce()>` closures at all. This is an implementation problem and it should be solved in the future; for now there is an unstable [`FnBox`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/trait.FnBox.html) trait to work around this.

Even another alternative would be to use references instead of values:

```
fn f<'a, T: 'a>(n: T) -> Box<Fn(T) -> T + 'a> where for<'b> &'b T: Add<T, Output=T> {
    Box::new(move |i: T| &n + i)
}
```

Now we specify that instead of `T`, `&'b T` for any lifetime `'b` must be summable with `T`. Here we use the fact that `Add` trait is overloaded for references to primitive types as well. This is probably the most generic version of this function.

Comment: The 
`fn f<'a, T: Add<Output=T> + Copy + 'a>(n: T) -> Box<Fn(T) -> T + 'a>`
working fine, e.g:
`assert_eq!(6, ff(2));`
, but 
`fn f2<'a, T: Add<Output=T> + 'a>(n: T) -> Box<FnOnce(T) -> T + 'a>`
seems unuseful for me. How I should use f2 ?

Comment: @seb_odessa please read the explanation below that example. I said that there are problems with it, including the problem with invocation of `Box<FnOnce>`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are OK with moving away from function calling, you could wrap the `x` in your own type:

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Adder<X> { 
    x: X 
}

impl<X: Copy> Adder<X> {
    fn add<Y: Add<X>>(&self, y: Y) -> <Y as Add<X>>::Output {
        y + self.x
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Adder { x: 1usize };

    x.add(2); // as opposed to x(2)
}
```

This means you can get rid of `Box` and don't need to allocate anything. Implementing `Fn(..)` is not possible in stable Rust, and the unstable version may break in future Rust versions. Look at [`std::ops::Fn`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) for further information.

Comment: Thank you, but it was interesting to implement a fn that return a function without helper structs.